# GET Request - Invalid HOST - ASP WEB API 2

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-web-api2, get-request

I uploaded my ASP.NET Web API 2 project onto the web using Azure.

[image]

But now that I have uploaded it (it is http), I cant get the GET request to work.

The problem is the Host parameter.

In the URL feild i put: www.website.com/api/Parts

I put the website URL in the Host Value field: www.website.com

[image]

This doesnt seem like a CORS issue.

How do I send a GET request to the online API?

Comment: You're replacing localhost with the correct url right ?

Comment: Yes I am , that is correct. It is just the URL without the /api/Parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are testing in POSTMAN. Just remove the `Host` parameter from header and test/send your API request again.

Answer (score 1):

Postman can not override Host header, it is blocked by default.
To allow Postman to send this header, install `Postman Interceptor` extension